# Redirecting to another page after django admin login

Tags: django, redirect, django-admin

I am making a custom administration page in Django. I do not want to reinvent the wheel and thus want to use Django admin login form for the staff to log in and redirect them to /my-url/ afterwards.

However, I can't find the way to redirect user to a custom url after successful login at /admin/.

Comment: If you're going to redirect users that login the **/admin/** they will have to visit /admin again to get in the **/admin/** if they'd want to? You should probably just decorate the custom view with **user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff)**

Comment: I want them to log in at /admin/ and afterwards be redirected to, for instance, /my-url/

Comment: I would rather extend the admin urls and/or templates if you are trying to keep administration in one place.

Answer (score 11):

since I stumbled across the same problem, I noticed the url of the the default login page:

```
/admin/login/?next=/admin/
```

so I changed the login page link to

```
/admin/login/?next=/
```

to point to the main page

works for the logout page too, nice and simple

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: where did you change this?

Comment: Nice, to complement: this is done using Django LOGIN_URL setting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#login-url

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue.
Instead of redirect *after login* I used the @staff_member_required decorator
for my view `/my-url/` which redirects to the admin login

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def test_list(request):
    return HttpResponse('TEST')
```

If class based views is used check out the [method_decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views)

Comment: @Daniel Backman , I know this is old, but how would you use this method when you are using class-based views, please ??

Comment: @mlwn check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views

Comment: @DanielBackman I solved the issue by using mixin... but your solution looks neater. Unfortunately, login page is redirecting me to localhost/accounts/login ... oops.. 404. I have already made changes to the admin template by using myadmin, copying the template to my project folder ... so, login should direct to localhost/myadmin/login instead.. any ideas please ?

Comment: am sorry, I mean  I didn't copy the template to my project, but by adding my own admin.py to main app in project and redirecting my homepage to it... I hope  I explained well...

Comment: Sorry.. :) you're great ... solved... I only have to specify the arguments of login_required as login_required(redirect_field_name='next', login_url='the login url') .... lol ... thanks alot....

Answer (score 3):

The Django auth app comes with a [login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) which you can hook up to `/accounts/login/` or any other url you choose. You can probably use the admin's login template `admin/login.html` if you don't want to write your own.

By using the login view, the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` parameter will work. The purpose of the `/admin/` page is to display the admin index. I would avoid trying to use it as the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in your `settings.py` file. Documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url).

Comment: Didn't work in the admin login page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `?next=` parameter set is not enough to set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in you setting.py. You need to also handel this parameter. As say docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url):

> LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
> Default: '/accounts/profile/'
>
> The URL or named URL pattern where requests are redirected after login
> **when the LoginView doesn’t get a next GET parameter.**

In my case I just set `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME = ""` instead of `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME = "next"` in my `django.contrib.auth` and it works fine.